# How can i suppress scientific notation on Matplotlib finance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using [MPL Finance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) to chart a candlestick chart, unfortunately the numbers on my y axis are in scientific notation while i'm trying to visualize them in decimal form. Is there any way to avoid that? Here is what i tried:

```
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df, type='candle', ... ,returnfig=True)
ax1 = axlist[0]
ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Where `df` is the dataframe that i'm using to chart. The previous code didn't give the expected output. I also tried that, but it didn't change how the numbers are plotted on the y axis:

```
fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df, type='candle', ... ,returnfig=True)
ax1 = axlist[0]
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.8f'))
```

Comment: Can you try `ax1.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False, style='plain')`

Comment: That worked too! The problem was that i was saving the chart in the wrong place!

Comment: In the future, don't forget to provide a complete working code. This was an incomplete code

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a newbie error: basically i was saving the chart on `mpf.plot()`, instead i should have saved that AFTER editing the chart, that's why i was not seeing my edits. Simply add at the end of the code: `fig.savefig('figure.png')` to see the chart with edited y axis.